# How to create KPI boxes in HTML inside power automate email body?

Tags: html, power-automate

How to create these KPI boxes in html inside power automate email body?
[image]

Comment: Inspect the HTML in that page and replicate it in the flow.

Comment: I'll try but the screenshot is from a tableau dashboard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.